# How can I use AJAX to save/update a widget form?

Tags: widgets, ajax, forms

My custom widget's form will have two pull-down menus: the content of the second menu is dependent on the user's selection in the first menu (think of the way Country and State/Province works).

I think the easiest implementation (though perhaps not the most user-friendly) would simply be to have the form automatically submit itself when the first pulldown is changed (ie: `<select onchange="submit_the_page_via_ajax()">`). I tried `onchange="this.form.submit();"` but that didn't leverage the Ajax call to my surprise (I would have thought that the sophisticated WordPress developers would have [hiJaxed](http://domscripting.com/presentations/xtech2006/) the form's submit event). They must be hijaxing the submit *button* however, since all my view source shows me is a standard html input type for the button.

Anyway, I would appreciate a little insight into a best practice for submitting a widget's form leveraging ajax. [This](http://www.thepicketts.org/2010/03/ajax-ifying-wordpress-widgets/) is a great post but only addresses the widget's display, not the back-end form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Save* buttons have a class `widget-control-save`, and this [is hooked up to `wpWidgets.save()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.3/wp-admin/js/widgets.dev.js#L50). So you either have to call `wpWidgets.save()`, or (probably easier) trigger a click event on the *Save* button.

Comment: Arg. so obvious. Thanks man. The link to the JS script is particularly useful. I didn't know where to look. Thanks!